# howto map the log4mongo Document to java object

Tags: mongodb, log4j, morphia

Basically my log4mongo is logging user activity and i want to select 
one user and view his log entries,

This code is working ok

```
BasicDBObject blogEntryDbObj = (BasicDBObject) 
mongo.getDB().getCollection("log").findOne(new BasicDBObject("_id", 
new ObjectId(blogEntryId)));
```

but here im getting the error "Trying to map to an unmapped class:

```
log = morphia.fromDBObject(log.class, blogEntryDbObj);
```

What should the `package` name be for the `log` class or maybe that
is irrelevant. I realize that probably my POJO is not correctly set up
but i cannot figure out what's wrong.

The log4mongo document look like this.

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("4eecf4e4f9cb90f308193614"), 
  "timestamp" : new Date("Sat, 17 Dec 2011 21:00:36 GMT +01:00"), 
  "level" : "INFO", 
  "thread" : "Server.Connection:146.53.243.167:4570", 
  "message" : "setting RegistrationId for: zambe", 
  "loggerName" : { 
    "fullyQualifiedClassName" : "zambe.afa8cc37-4796-49c1- 
a175-05a8daf0a88c", 
    "package" : ["zambe", "afa8cc37-4796-49c1-a175-05a8daf0a88c"], 
    "className" : "afa8cc37-4796-49c1-a175-05a8daf0a88c" 
  }, 
  "fileName" : "PushUpdateRegistrationId.java", 
  "method" : "connect", 
  "lineNumber" : "61", 
  "class" : { 
    "fullyQualifiedClassName" : 
"com.carlsberg.server.PushUpdateRegistrationId", 
    "package" : ["com", "carlsberg", "server", 
"PushUpdateRegistrationId"], 
    "className" : "PushUpdateRegistrationId" 
  }, 
  "host" : { 
    "process" : "5832@ERIKSWEDMINI", 
    "name" : "ERIKSWEDMINI", 
    "ip" : "192.168.1.150" 
  } 
}
```

Here is my POJO im trying to map to

```
@Entity(value = "log") 
public class log 
{ 
    @Id private ObjectId id; 
    Date timestamp; 
    Level level; 
    String thread;
    String message; 

    @Embedded  
    LoggerName loggerName; 

    String fileName; 
    String method; 
    String lineNumber; 

    @Embedded("class") 
    LoggerClass loggerClass; 

    @Embedded
    MyHost host; 
} 

@Entity(noClassnameStored=true) 
@Embedded 
class LoggerName 
{ 
    String fullyQualifiedClassName; 
    @Property("package") 
    String[] _package; 
    String className; 

} 

@Entity(noClassnameStored=true) 
@Embedded 
class LoggerClass 
{ 
    String fullyQualifiedClassName; 
    @Property("package") 
    String[] _package; 
    String className; 

} 

@Entity(noClassnameStored=true) 
@Embedded 
class MyHost 
{ 
    String process; 
    String name;
    String ip;
}
```

Comment: Did you map your log class first? http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/MappingObjects

Comment: @Nat no i did not, I was mapping it at the wrong place. now it's working. Post the answer and i will accept it. "mapping is instance method. You need to map it on the same instance of Morphia to get fromDBObject to work. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`morphia.map` is instance method. You need to `morphia.map` it on the same instance of Morphia to get `morphia.fromDBObject` to work